# How to set background Color of dynamically created Textview?

Tags: android, textview

I am creating dynamic textview in android. The view is created but when I am clicking on textview I want to set the background colour of that particular textview in android. I have tried but it sets the colour to only last textview not selected textview.

here is my code

```
public class Demo extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private LinearLayout llOptions;
    private TextView textView, tvOptionFirstQue;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final int MY_BUTTON = 9000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_quiz_demo);
        llOptions = findViewById(R.id.llOptions);
        tvOptionFirstQue = findViewById(R.id.tvOptionFirstQue);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            textView = new TextView(Demo
                    .this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            float left = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.common_twentyfive);
            float top = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.common_five);
            float toppadding = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.common_twelve);
            float right = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.common_twentyfive);
            params.setMargins((int) left, (int) top, (int) right, 0);
            textView.setPadding(0, (int) toppadding, 0, (int) toppadding);
            textView.setTextSize(14);
            textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background_light_gray);
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            textView.setId(i);
            textView.setLayoutParams(params);
            textView.setText("test" + i);
            textView.setOnClickListener(this);
            arrayList.add(textView.getText().toString());
            this.llOptions.addView(textView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case 0:
                View child = llOptions.getChildAt(v.getId());
                TextView textView1 = (TextView) child;
                onFirstOptionClisk(textView1);


        }
    }

    private void onFirstOptionClisk(TextView textView) {
        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_lightblue_answer_backgroun);
        textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    }
```

Comment: I dont think onFirstOptionClisk() is even called since even if you set the id to 0 I dont think thats how it works. Check if the click is possible firrst

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
textView.setBackgroundResource(getResources.getColor(R.color.black));
```

And remove -

```
 textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background_light_gray)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of your issue is that you are creating a class variable TextView as textView and each time in your for look only this is updated with a new referance and as a result only the last textView persist. This is a type of logica issue.

Now the solution is that you create new object of your TextView in the for loop so different object reference will be added to the LinearLayout llOptions. The only thing that you need to do is that delete class variable for textView and creat object each time in for loop:

```
public class Demo extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private LinearLayout llOptions;
private TextView tvOptionFirstQue; //Comment by Hari: textView removed from here.
private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private static final int MY_BUTTON = 9000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_quiz_demo);
    llOptions = findViewById(R.id.llOptions);
    tvOptionFirstQue = findViewById(R.id.tvOptionFirstQue);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(Demo
                .this); //Comment by Hari: creating TextView object each time so that new reference will be created each time instead of over writing the same reference each time.
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        //Rest are unchanged......
```

Hope it will solve your issue. Let me know your experience.

Comment: This is proper answer and it should be accepted I think.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
```

instead

```
textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background_light_gray)
```

will work